# Visual Studio For Mac Compile Errors

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am attempting to develop a C# Xamarin app with VS2017 on Mac.  I have been developing on Windows for years now, but am baffled by a few compile errors I am receiving on my Mac.

The errors are found in xaml.g.cs files which I have never seen before.  This is a link to a .zip of my project, can someone assist me in tracking down and remedying the issue?

These are my compile errors:

> /Users/owner/Projects/XF_Login/XF_Login/obj/Debug/netstandard2.0/Pages/RegisterPage.xaml.g.cs(6,6): Error CS0579: Duplicate 'global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute' attribute (CS0579) (XF_Login)’
>
> /Users/owner/Projects/XF_Login/XF_Login/obj/Debug/netstandard2.0/Pages/RegisterPage.xaml.g.cs(22,22): Error CS0111: Type 'RegisterPage' already defines a member called 'InitializeComponent' with the same parameter types (CS0111) (XF_Login)

**edit**
I have tried deleting the obj/Debug folder, and cleaning, then rebuilding, but the folder is re-created and the error remains.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W2yHpg7VuCS8yLoxWMjXsZdAdDQfhbic

Comment: Read [ask], include relevant code and errors in your question and show what you have tried to resolve them.

Comment: please post the text of the errors.  SO is not a free debugging service - expecting us to download your code and debug it for you is really presumptuous.

Comment: @CodeCaster - sorry the tap to click got the best of me.  I added in my compile errors.

Comment: @Jason - I have posted my errors - sorry the Tap To Click got the best of me and my post submitted before I could copy/paste them in.

Comment: Have you examined the code in question?  And looked for the duplicate code?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - I have examined the code in ? and I have tried commenting out the duplicate code, but to no avail.  I do not understand why the "g" is being added to the filenames nor how to fix :(

Comment: the g.cs file is generated by the compiler tools - it contains mappings between XAML elements and their corresponding objects in the code behind

Comment: @Jason - so the issue lies somewhere in my RegisterPage.xaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LoggedInMain.xaml` has the wrong `x:Class` definition

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XF_Login.Pages.RegisterPage"  >
```

Comment: That remedied.  How did you track the error down to the LoggedInMain.xaml when IMO none of the compile errors pointed to that?

Comment: I did a global search for "RegisterPage"